# How to fix :File Upload error in localhost?

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

this is a part of code I am using to upload video to my website, the code is running perfectly on my server but in localhost (xampp) it always returns the error statement and doesn't upload the video, this is the code for parsing the upload

```
<?php

$file = (isset($_FILES["image"]) ? $_FILES["image"] : 0);

if (!$file) { // if file not chosen
    die("ERROR: Please browse for a file before clicking the upload button");
}
if($file["error"]) {

echo '<script>';
  echo 'console.log('. json_encode( $file["error"] ) .')';
  echo '</script>';
    die("ERROR: File couldn't be processed");

}
        $path = $_FILES['image']['name'];
        $ext = pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
        $tmp_file = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
        $fileName = $_FILES['image']['name'];
        $fileName = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9.]/", "", $fileName);
        $thumb = explode('.', $fileName);
        $thumbname = $thumb[0];
        $thumbname = $thumbname . ".jpg";
        $file_path = "images/video/" . $fileName;
        $imagename = "category_" . time() . "." . $ext;
        move_uploaded_file($tmp_file, $file_path)
?>
```

and this is the code of function to upload video and it is POST request

```
function uploadFile() {
  var file = _("image").files[0];
   //alert(file.name+" | "+file.size+" | "+file.type);
  var formdata = new FormData();
  formdata.append("image", file);
  var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
  ajax.upload.addEventListener("progress", progressHandler, false);
  ajax.addEventListener("load", completeHandler, false);
  ajax.addEventListener("error", errorHandler, false);
  ajax.addEventListener("abort", abortHandler, false);
  ajax.open("POST", "file_upload_parser.php"); // http://www.developphp.com/video/JavaScript/File-Upload-Progress-Bar-Meter-Tutorial-Ajax-PHP
  //use file_upload_parser.php from above url
  ajax.send(formdata);
}
```

this is the error message

```
console.log(1)ERROR: File couldn't be processed
```

my php versionis 7.2.8

Comment: you did not post the error so i will have to sacrifice an intern and from his blood divine that you probably have not created a temp/destination folder in your local environment or that your web service user does not have rights to right one or both of those folders. Next time please include error messages. I dont like the sounds that interns make when they are being sacrificed.

Comment: I have updated the question @SimasJoneliunas

Comment: you should check phpinfo() for `post_max_size`, `file_uploads` and `upload_max_size` -> make sure your file doesn't exceed the sizes and that `file_uploads` is On

Comment: Lookup what the errors mean: http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you check your `upload_max_filesize directive in php.ini` ? . sorry i can't add a comment

and add this after the checking part and inside the failed condition

```
print_r($_FILES["image"]["error"]);
```

and show us the result of it .

Comment: thank you so much, upload max size was 2M, Updated it and my problem has solved